# Remove tuple based on character count

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, character

I have a dataset consisting of tuple of words. I want to remove words that contain less than 4 characters, but I could not figure out a way to iterate my codes.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
                   content                clean4Char
0         [yes, no, never]                   [never]
1    [to, every, contacts]         [every, contacts]
2 [words, tried, describe]  [words, tried, describe]
3          [word, you, go]                    [word]
```

Here is the code that I'm working with (it keeps showing me error warning).

```
def remove_single_char(text):
    text = [word for word in text]
    return re.sub(r"\b\w{1,3}\b"," ", word)

df['clean4Char'] = df['content'].apply(lambda x: remove_single_char(x))
df.head(3)
```

Comment: Does each column contains a _list_, or just a comma separated _string_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is with your `remove_single_char` function. This will do the job:

Also there is no need to use lambda since you already are passing a function to `applay`

```
def remove(input):
    return list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 4, input))

df['clean4Char'] = df['content'].apply(remove)
df.head(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.replace` here for a Pandas option:

```py
df["clean4Char"] = df["content"].str.replace(r'\b\w{1,3}\b,?\s*', '', regex=True)
```

The regex used here says to match:

- `\b` a word boundary (only match entire words)
- `\w{1,3}` a word with no more than 3 characters
- `\b` closing word boundary
- `,?` optional comma
- `\s*` optional whitespace

We then replace with empty string to effectively remove the 3 letter or less matching words along with optional trailing whitespace and comma.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eNfcar/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.